# Vertically align parent elements to line up middle child elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have content blocks that each contain a title, an image, and copy. I need to vertically align the blocks so that the images line up any time they are in the same row.

The code below illustrates a width at which my layout breaks. I can't make the title or copy a fixed height without breaking the spacing between rows. I can't put the titles or copy in their own row because the title image and copy have to stay together as the blocks flow to new rows.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700');
.container {
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  flex-basis: 190px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto .5em auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 225px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;
  /* height: 4.75em; */
  margin: .25em auto 0 auto;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h3>The Title One</h3>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/225">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>The Title Two</h3>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/225">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>The Longer Title Three</h3>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/225">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS alone can’t align the images vertically, because the individual blocks aren’t related – one title doesn’t know how tall another is. The answer above is a reasonable stab at the problem, but not very robust, as you noticed.

You could come closer if you can use CSS Grid, but then you’d lose the wrapping behaviour of the flex row.

I can’t think of anything but a JavaScript solution: figuring out which blocks are on the same row, measuring which title is the tallest, and assigning that height to the others.

Another approach could be to change the design, e.g. by moving the titles to below the images. After all, aligning these images while having titles of arbitrary lengths above them seems like a strange combination of constraints.

Comment: The titles are the same height in the Sketch file our designer sent me, but it's up to me to make the design responsive. I don't have the liberty to move the title, but I guess I could keep the blocks from scaling and just let them flow to a new row sooner.

Comment: That’s an option, but it will still not always work. In my experience, a situation like this is a perfect opportunity to get back to the designer and discuss the challenge at hand. Hopefully, they will understand how this particular combination of design choices has its challenges with varying dimensions for the parts like texts and images. Typically, these will arise only when creating the design in the browser, and experimenting with actual (or better demo) content. Then you could share some ideas to solve those, exchanging both design and development perspectives.

Answer (score 1):

I think `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` will help you.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700');
.container {
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  flex-basis: 190px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto .5em auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 225px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;
  /* height: 4.75em; */
  margin: .25em auto 0 auto;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h3>The Title One</h3>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/225">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>The Title Two</h3>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/225">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>The Longer Title Three</h3>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/225">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `align-items: center` is a good thought. The images are pretty close to aligned at this width, but when the text flows differently it's further off.